# Maintaining a distributed contact list and accessing in an email client

Tags: contacts, distributed, email, email-client

I am working on a project. I have many databases in which email contacts are maintained. Each database is location on a different server and each of them is used by different personnels to send emails. I want to unify these contacts, keep them sync and available to all the personnel who broadcast mails.

**My solution:** This is a distributed solution. Maintain continuously updated XML file on each server. When a broadcast mail is composed, fetch all files, merge them etc.

**My question:** How can I integrate this solution with an email client. Which opensource client is suitable for this? I want the phonebook to be updated when compose button is clicked.

I am open to other suggestions. May be some opensource solution that works out of the box for me.

Comment: I have done it. :) I hope now someone ansswers this one!

Comment: Thanks for accepting more answers @Affan.  Sorry to not have a good answer to your question.  You might try coming back with a more specific question.  The scope of this one is just too broad.